# Should I use proxies with simplexml_load_file and file_get_contents?

Tags: php, proxy, rss, simplexml, file-get-contents

I'm using `simplexml_load_file` to get RSS from several websites for a while.

Sometimes I get errors from some of these websites and for about 5 days I'm having errors from 2 specific websites.

Here are the errors from `simplexml_load_file`:

```
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(http://example.com/feed): failed to open stream: Connection timed out 

PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://example.com/feed"
```

Here are the errors from `file_get_contents`:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://example.com/page): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

That's how I'm using `simplexml_load_file`:

```
simplexml_load_file( $url );
```

That's how I'm using `file_get_contents`:

```
file_get_contents( $url );
```

Is that because I'm not using a proxy or invalid arguments?

UPDATE:
The 2 websites are using something like a firewall or a service to check for robots:

```
Accessing http://example.com/feed securely…
This is an automatic process. Your browser will redirect to your requested content in 5 seconds.
```

Comment: So, the website is using a service to detect robots, and your code is a robot, so the service is detecting your code and denying it access. Sounds like the site doesn't want you to access it that way, and is working as intended.

Comment: @IMSoP, It's doing that to prevent DDos and similar types of attacks, I just want to read the RSS

Comment: Sure, but your question still amounts to "how can I get around this (unidentified) site protection". If it's misbehaving, talk to the site owner or the vendor of the protection; if you're doing something the site owner doesn't want you to do, don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You're relying on an assumption that `http://example.com/feed` is *always* going to exist and *always* return exactly the content you're looking for. As you've discovered, this is a bad assumption.

You're attempting to access the network with your `file_get_contents()` and  `simplexml_load_file()` and finding out that sometimes those call fail. You must **always** plan for these calls to fail. It doesn't matter if some websites openly allow this kind of behavior or if you have very reliable web host. There are circumstances out of your control, such as an Internet backbone outage, that will eventually cause your application to get back a bad response. In your situation, the third party has blocked you. This is one of the failures that happen with network requests.

The first take away is that **you must handle the failure better**. You cannot do this with `file_get_contents()` because `file_get_contents()` was designed to get the contents of files. In my opinion the PHP implementers that allowed it to make network calls made a very serious mistake allowing it this functionality. I'd recommend using curl:

```
function doRequest($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    if () {
        return $output;
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Sorry, an error occurred');
    }
}
```

Using this you will be able to handle errors (they *will* happen) better for your own users.

You're second problem is that this specific host is giving you a 403 error. This is *probably* intentional on their end. I would assume that this is them telling you that they don't want you using their website like this. However you will need to engage them specifically and ask them what you can do. They might ask you to use a real API, they might just ignore you entirely, they might even tell you to pound sand - but there isn't anything that we can do to advise here. This is strictly a problem (or feature) with their software and you must contact them directly for advice.

You could potentially use multiple IP addresses to connect to websites and rotate IPs each time one gets blocked. But doing so would be considered a malicious attack on their service.